# Azure search service index pointing multiple document db collections

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search, indexer

How to load data from two separate collections of azure cosmos db to a single azure search index? I need a solution to join the data from two collections in a way similar to inner joining concept of SQL and load that data to azure search service.

I have two collections in azure cosmos db.
One for product and sample documents for the same is as below.

```
{
   "description": null,
   "links": [],
   "replaces": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   "replacedBy": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   "productTypeId": "ccd0bc73-c4a1-41bf-9c96-454a5ba1d025",
   "id": "a4853bf5-9c58-4fb5-a1ff-fc3ab575b4c8",
   "name": "New Product",
   "createDate": "2018-09-19T10:04:35.1951552Z",
   "createdBy": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   "updateDate": "2018-10-05T13:46:24.7048358Z",
   "updatedBy": "DIJdyXMudaqeAdsw1SiNyJKRIi7Ktio5@clients"
 }
 {
   "description": null,
   "links": [],
   "replaces": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   "replacedBy": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   "productTypeId": "ccd0bc73-c4a1-41bf-9c96-454a5ba1d025",
   "id": "b9b6c3bc-a8f8-470f-ac93-be589eb1da16",
   "name": "New Product 2",
   "createDate": "2018-09-19T11:02:02.6919008Z",
   "createdBy": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   "updateDate": "2018-09-19T11:02:02.6919008Z",
   "updatedBy": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
 }
 {
   "description": null,
   "links": [],
   "replaces": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   "replacedBy": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   "productTypeId": "ccd0bc73-c4a1-41bf-9c96-454a5ba1d025",
   "id": "98b3647a-3b40-4a00-bd0f-2a397bd48b68",
   "name": "New Product 7",
   "createDate": "2018-09-20T09:42:28.2913567Z",
   "createdBy": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   "updateDate": "2018-09-20T09:42:28.2913567Z",
   "updatedBy": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
 }
```

Another collection for ProductType with below sample document.

```
{
  "description": null,
  "links": null,
  "replaces": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "replacedBy": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "id": "ccd0bc73-c4a1-41bf-9c96-454a5ba1d025",
  "name": "ProductType1_186",
  "createDate": "2018-09-18T23:54:43.9395245Z",
  "createdBy": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "updateDate": "2018-10-05T13:29:44.019851Z",
  "updatedBy": "DIJdyXMudaqeAdsw1SiNyJKRIi7Ktio5@clients"
}
```

The product type id is referred in product collection and that is the column which links both the collections.

I want to load the above two collections to the same azure search service index and I expect my field of index to be populated somewhat like below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use product id as the key, you can simply point two indexers at the same index, and Azure Search will merge the documents automatically. For example, here are two indexer definitions that would merge their data into the same index:

`{
  "name" : "productIndexer",
  "dataSourceName" : "productDataSource",
  "targetIndexName" : "combinedIndex",
  "schedule" : { "interval" : "PT2H" }
}`

`{
  "name" : "sampleIndexer",
  "dataSourceName" : "sampleDataSource",
  "targetIndexName" : "combinedIndex",
  "schedule" : { "interval" : "PT2H" }
}`

Learn more about the create indexer api [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-indexer)

However, it appears that the two collections share the same fields. This means that the fields from the document which gets indexed last will replace the fields from the document that got indexed first. To avoid this, I would recommend replacing the fields that match the `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` pattern with `null` in your Cosmos DB query. For example:

`SELECT productTypeId, (createdBy != "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ? createdBy : null) as createdBy FROM products`

This exact query may not work for your use case. See the [query syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-reference) for more information.

Please let me know if you have any questions, or something is not working as expected.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Hi Matt, but the ProductType collection does not have a field that contains product id. And indexer creation for product type collection fails with error `Ensure that the 'ProductId' column is present in the data source, or add a field mapping that maps one of the existing column names to 'ProductId'`.

Comment: DevMJ, looks like you'll have to use a column that's common to both collections. I think you mentioned product type id was this column?

Comment: Yes Matt , ProductTypeId is the column that is common to both collections. But I need ProductId as the key column in my index. There are multiple products with same product type id and I want to list all my products in my index. When I used product type id as the key column I was getting only single product listed for individual product type id.